# Calculate number keeping it within range of 0.6 to 3.0

Tags: php, logic, tag-cloud

I'm creating a tag cloud and trying to base each tags fontsize dynamically based on a the number of references a tag has.

So as a sample set:

```
car, 34
truck, 354
bike, 1230
bicycle, 3
```

With the above sample set I need to figure out each value as a value within a certain range of min 0.6 and maximum 3.0.

Taking `1230` as the max value and `1` as the minimum value.

The calculation I'm using is below but it seems to be inverted which I can't figure out, the outputted values are rounded.

car:

```
((1230 - 34) / (1230 - 1) * (3 - 0.6)) + 0.6
= 2.96
```

truck:

```
((1230 - 354) / (1230 - 1) * (3 - 0.6)) + 0.6
= 2.31
```

bike:

```
((1230 - 1230) / (1230 - 1) * (3 - 0.6)) + 0.6
= 0.6
```

bicycle:

```
((1230 - 3) / (1230 - 1) * (3 - 0.6)) + 0.6
= 3.0
```

Essentially, the higher the number the higher the value output up to a maximum of 3.0, all help appreciate.

Comment: I think the formula should be `x/1229*2.4+0.6` or in Variable terms: `X/Max*Range+Base`

Comment: https://ideone.com/qRsLAp

Comment: @Dharman, nice one, working perfectly based on that calculation.